# Android TableView Header

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I'm looking to create a custom renderer to style the TableView Headers on Android devices. Right now it is defaulted to the black background and blue text. How can I reference the header inside the custom renderer?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe define an android theme? http://blog.masterdevs.com/xf-day-6/

Comment: Thanks for the link, I overlooked themes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need a custom renderer for that. You can simply setup the layout for your header even from XAML for your listview the exact same way you would do with the cells, the only difference is that you'll use the "GroupHeaderTemplate" element of the listview, like this:

```
    <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
            ... set anything you want here for layout, styling, etc.
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate >
```

Just a reminder, you are using the same format and the "ItemTemplate" element of the listview when you are styling the cells.

Comment: I'm looking to customize the header of a TableView where there is no GroupHeaderTemplate property. I was unaware of that until I was deep into a TableView.

Comment: Maybe you'd be better off with using a ListView?

Answer (score 0):

Mario's comment answers my question the best. If I want to customize the header of a TableView, then my best option would be to style it or use a theme.